# Angular: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to upload an image after cropping it in angular 2,but the fileReader returns with the error stating file is not of the type blob.

Here is the html:

```
    <input type="file"
           accept="image/*"
           (change)="processFile($event)">

<button *ngIf="imageChangedEvent" (click)="uploadImage()"
                                  type="button">Upload Image</button>

<image-cropper
    [imageChangedEvent]="imageChangedEvent"
    [maintainAspectRatio]="true"
    [aspectRatio]="4 / 3"
    [resizeToWidth]="422"
    format="png"
    (imageCropped)="imageCropped($event)"
></image-cropper>
```

ts file:

```
class FileSnippet{
  static readonly IMAGE_SIZE={width:750,height:422}
  constructor(public src:string,public file:File){}
}
//component starts
  selectedFile:FileSnippet;
  imageChangedEvent:any;
  imageCropped(file:File){
    if(this.selectedFile){
      return this.selectedFile.file=file;
    }
    return this.selectedFile= new FileSnippet('',file);
  }
  processFile(event:any){
    this.selectedFile=undefined;
    const URL=window.URL;
    let file,img;
    if((file=event.target.files[0]) && (file.type==='image/jpeg' || file.type==='image/png')){
      img=new Image();
      const self=this;
      img.onload=function(){
        if(this.width>FileSnippet.IMAGE_SIZE.width && this.height>FileSnippet.IMAGE_SIZE.height){
          self.imageChangedEvent=event; 
        }
      }
      img.src=URL.createObjectURL(file);
    }else{
    }
  }

  uploadImage(){
    if(this.selectedFile){
      const reader=new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener('load',(event:any)=>{
        //upload image using service
      });
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.selectedFile.file);

    }
  }
}
```

When i try to upload the files without cropping them, the fileReader works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding outputType="blob" to image cropper

Comment: still doesnt work. Releases of the npm say outputType is removed